# web api versioning with default link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have web api with two version v1 and v2, they are like folders in controllers, these folders contains controllers with same names and methods.
My WebApiConfig looks like this

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi", 
            "api/v{version}/{controller}/{id}",
            new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new HttpControllerSelector((config)));
```

Respectively my links looks like `api/v1/custum/get?id=3` and `api/v2/custum/get?id=3`, how I can do navigation in link `api/custum/get?=3` at last version i.e. at `v2/custum/get?id=3`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value for the version parameter like this

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
            new
            {
                version="v2",
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
```

Comment: Please look at my example, I replace v{version}  to {version}

Comment: I see, but when I get it in HttpControllerDescriptor  public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var controllers = GetControllerMapping();

            var routeData = request.GetRouteData(); it has only two parameters and version == controllerName

Answer (score 0):

Have a route config for versioned API and a fallback config. For example,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "VersionedApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The first one maps the calls with specific version. The second one has no version in the route. In your `HttpControllerSelector`, try to get value for `version`, if it is not there for the second route config, set it to a default version.